# Pass action name to Handlebars helper that should be in helper output

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a FontAwesome handlebars helper that can also add an action to the html output.

The handlebars helper takes `color` and `action` as optional parameters:

```
Em.Handlebars.helper('icon', function (iconName, options) {
    var returnString = '';

    options = options.hash;

    returnString += "<i class='icon-" + Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(iconName) + "'";
    returnString += options.color ? " style='color: " + options.color + "'" : "";
    returnString += options.action ? " {{action '" + options.action + "'}}" : "";
    returnString += "></i>";

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(returnString);
});
```

And here is how I am using it:

```
{{icon 'angle-right' action='expand'}}
```

Action in controller looks like this:

```
actions: {
    expand: function() {
        console.log('expanded!');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work... When I click the icon, nothing is logged. Is it not possible for Handlebars helpers to output Handlebars code this way? Is there another way of adding an action to the html output element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is where you'd want to use a component instead of a Handlebars helper. (Handlebars helpers are very limited in what they can do.)

```
App.FontAwesomeIconComponent = Em.Component.extend({
    color: '',
    styleAttribute: function() {
        return 'color:' + this.get('color') + ';';
    }.property('color'),

    icon: '',
    fullIconName: function() {
        return 'icon-' + this.get('icon');
    }.property('icon')
});
```

Then, for your template:

```
<i {{bind-attr class='fullIconName' style=styleAttribute}}
    {{action 'iconClicked' on='click'}}>
</i>
```

Then, you can use it like so:

```
{{font-awesome-icon icon='angle-right' color='blue' iconClicked=expand}}
```

This will then call the `expand` action in your controller when the icon is clicked.

Comment: Turned out that the action was supposed to be on the parent anyway. But this is a great answer and I will definitely use the suggested component.